# Lost connection to MySQL server during query? Python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, optimization

I am constantly listening to a port with python. I make about 500 inserts per minute in that port. It gives this warning when the number of inserts increases at a time. And the program stops working. It does not insert new incoming data.

Python code:

```
import socket  
import MySQLdb
import sys
import thread
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

con = None
dbhost = 'localhost'
dbport   = 3306
dbuser = ""
dbpass = ""
dbname = ""

class DB:
  conn = None

  def connect(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname)

  def query(self, sql):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    try:
      cursor = self.conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute(sql)
    except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
      self.connect()
      cursor = self.conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute(sql)
      self.conn.commit()
      self.conn.autocommit(True)
    return cursor

def veritabani_islemleri(mesaj):
  try:  
    parcala = mesaj.split("#")
    i=0
    j=len(parcala)
    while i < (j-1):
      table_list= parcala[i].split(";")
      location= table_list[0].split(",")     
      if(location[0]=='$GEOLOC' and str(location[2])!='' and len(table_list)==14):
        mesafe= table_list[13].split(",")      
        date_data= str(table_list[1])+" "+str(table_list[2])
        data = datetime.strptime(date_data,'%d%m%Y %H%M%S')
        data = data + timedelta(hours=3)
        date_tim = data.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        date_tim = data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        if(str(location[3])=='-' or str(location[3])=='2'):
          cur = db.query('INSERT INTO table VALUES("%i","%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (int(location[2]),int(location[1]), 'GEO', date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
          if(int(location[2])==861359034946341):
            cur = db.query('INSERT INTO gps_table( ) VALUES("%i","%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (123456,int(location[1]), 'GEO', date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
        elif(str(location[3])=='IX' or str(location[3])=='IO'):
          cur = db.query('INSERT INTO table_stat() VALUES("%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (int(location[2]), str(location[3]), date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
          if(int(location[2])==861359034946341):
            cur = db.query('INSERT INTO table_stat() VALUES("%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (123456, str(location[3]), date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
          if(str(location[3])=='IO'):
            cur = db.query('INSERT INTO gps_table() VALUES("%i","%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (int(location[2]), int(location[1]), str(location[3]), date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),0,int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
            if(int(location[2])==861359034946341):
              cur = db.query('INSERT INTO gps_table() VALUES("%i","%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (123456, int(location[1]), str(location[3]), date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),0,int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
          if(str(location[3])=='IX'):
            cur = db.query('INSERT INTO gps_table() VALUES("%i","%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (int(location[2]), int(location[1]), str(location[3]), date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),-1,int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
            if(int(location[2])==861359034946341):
              cur = db.query('INSERT INTO gps_table() VALUES("%i","%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (123456, int(location[1]), str(location[3]), date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),-1,int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
        elif(str(location[3])=="I3L" or str(location[3])=="I3H"): 
          cur = db.query('INSERT INTO panic() VALUES("%i","%s","%f","%f","%i")' % (int(location[2]), date_tim, float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),1))
        elif(str(location[3])=="I2L" or str(location[3])=="I2H"):
          cur = db.query('INSERT INTO panic() VALUES("%i","%s","%f","%f","%i")' % (int(location[2]), date_tim, float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),1))
        else:
          cur = db.query('INSERT INTO gps_table() VALUES("%i","%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (int(location[2]),int(location[1]), 'GEO', date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
          if(int(location[2])==861359034946341):
            cur = db.query('INSERT INTO gps_table() VALUES("%i","%i", "%s", "%s","%f","%f","%i","%i","%i","%i","%s","%s","%s","%i","%i")' % (123456,int(location[1]), 'GEO', date_tim,float(table_list[3][1:]),float(table_list[4][2:]),int(table_list[5]),int(table_list[6]),int(table_list[7]),int(table_list[8]),str(table_list[9]),str(table_list[10]),str(table_list[11]),int(table_list[12]),int(mesafe[0])))
      elif(location[0]=='$TRIP' and str(location[2])!='' and len(table_list)==32):      
        date_data= str(location[3])+" "+str(table_list[1])
        data = datetime.strptime(date_data,'%d%m%Y %H%M%S')
        data = data + timedelta(hours=3)
        date_tim = data.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') 
        date_tim = data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
        date_data= str(table_list[11])+" "+str(table_list[12])
        data = datetime.strptime(date_data,'%d%m%Y %H%M%S')
        data = data + timedelta(hours=3)
        date_tim2 = data.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') 
        date_tim2 = data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        cur = db.query('INSERT INTO table_trip() VALUES("%i","%s","%s","%i","%f", "%f", "%i", "%i", "%i", "%i")' % (int(location[2]), date_tim2,date_tim,int(table_list[22]), float(table_list[23]), float(table_list[24]), int(table_list[25]), int(table_list[27]), int(table_list[29]), int(table_list[30])))             
        if(int(location[2])==861359034946341):
          cur = db.query('INSERT INTO table_trip() VALUES("%i","%s","%s","%i","%f", "%f", "%i", "%i", "%i", "%i")' % (123456, date_tim2,date_tim,int(table_list[22]), float(table_list[23]), float(table_list[24]), int(table_list[25]), int(table_list[27]), int(table_list[29]), int(table_list[30])))             
      elif(location[0]=="$LOGIN" and str(location[2])!='' and len(table_list)==3):
        tel = table_list[2].split(",")
        cur = db.query('INSERT INTO login_pac() VALUES("%i","%i")' % (int(location[2]),int(tel[0])))
      elif(location[0]=="$SPEED" and str(location[2])!='' and len(table_list)==13):
        date_data= str(location[3])+" "+str(table_list[1])
        data = datetime.strptime(date_data,'%d%m%Y %H%M%S')
        data = data + timedelta(hours=3)
        date_tim = data.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') 
        date_tim = data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
        cur = db.query('INSERT INTO speed_pac() VALUES("%i","%s","%f","%f","%i", "%i", "%i", "%i")' % (int(location[2]), date_tim, float(table_list[2][1:]), float(table_list[3][2:]), int(table_list[4]), int(table_list[6]), int(table_list[11]), int(table_list[12].replace(',',''))))                
      elif(location[0]=="$ALIVE" and str(location[2])!='' and len(table_list)==1):
        cur = db.query('INSERT INTO alive_paketleri() VALUES("%i","%i")' % (int(location[1]),int(location[2])))

      i = i+1
    #print addr, ' >> ', mesaj
  except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    dosya = open('/asd/fgh/logs.txt','a')
    dosya.write('\n')
    dosya.write("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1]))
    dosya.flush()
    dosya.close()
    i = i + 1



def on_new_client(clientsocket,addr):
  msg = ''
  while True:
    try:
      dosya_ismi = "/asd/pfgh/logs/"+str(addr[0])+".txt"
      dosya_ismi = dosya_ismi.replace(',','').replace(' ','')
      print "artik mesaj:",msg
      msg = str(msg)+clientsocket.recv(1024)
      msg = [x.replace(' ','').replace("\n","") for x in msg]
      #msg = [x.split("\n") for x in msg]
      msg = ''.join(msg)
      print addr, ' >> ', msg
      msg = msg.replace('\n','').replace("""
""",'')
      if len(msg)>1 :
        lngt = len(msg)-1
      else:
        break
      print "Son karakter:"+str(msg[lngt])
      dosya = open('/asd/fgh/logs.txt','a')
      dosya.write('\n')
      dosya.write(msg)
      dosya.flush()
      dosya.close() 
      if msg[lngt]=='#' :
        veritabani_islemleri(msg)
        msg= ''
      else:
        print "ha buraya girdi"
        msg = str(msg)+'#'
        print "else dustu: ",msg
        #veritabani_islemleri(msg)
    except Exception as e:
      print e
      e = str(e)+'#'
      dosya = open('/asd/fgh/logs.txt','a')
      dosya.write('\n')
      dosya.write(str(e))
      dosya.flush()
      dosya.close() 
      break
  clientsocket.close()



s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = 'ip_address'    # Get local machine name
port = 123                 # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
s.table_listn(50)                 # Now wait for client connection.

#con = MySQLdb.connect(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname);
db = DB()
while True:
  while True:
     c, addr = s.accept()    
     thread.start_new_thread(on_new_client,(c,addr))
```

Is there an error in Python code? Or with mysql?

Plesk warinig: "The server's health parameter "Services> MySQL memory usage" changed from "yellow" to "red"."

But I don't do much select on the server. 80% of transactions insert.

Comment: Can you log when your connect() function called? you are not using singleton so it would override the current `Db.conn` whenever you call `connect()`.

Comment: How can I do it? @hunzter

Comment: Just add a `print("calling connect")` your connect function and run the code again. I think you are calling multiple times, which override the current `Db.conn` variable each time.

Comment: How many times does that code connect to the database?  Are the multiple threads?  (500 inserts per minute is trivial for MySQL if you have one thread with one connection.)